# How do I sync GSuite User data with Salesforce so that I only have to manage my users' data in GSuite?

Tags: lightning, google

My team is trying to configure GSuite so that, when our users log into Salesforce their data is updated to match what is stored for their user in GSuite.

It's worth noting the following:

- We have integrated with Single Sign-On, so our users log in to
  Salesforce with Google;
- Data from the name and surname fields are
  pulling through from GSuite successfully.
- The issue is coming in
  where we are unsure of how or where in GSuite we should configure the
  integration with Salesforce to enable us to sync other data (stored
  in GSuite).

The end goal is that we will only have to maintain our users' data in GSuite